# How can I see the WiFi password my iPhone is using?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, security

My iPhone is connected to my home network. I'm setting a new computer up with Windows, and it's asking me for the WiFi password.

If I don't want to go in a different part of the house to look for it, **can I find what the WiFi network's password is from my iPhone**?

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken?  If not, the only way to see the password is sync your access via Keychain to your Mac and view it there.

Comment: I understand. As I said I was looking for it to set up a Windows machine. Thanks

Comment: Yep, I was thinking if you can get it to a Mac to view in Keychain then you can use it on your Windows PC.  BTW, can't you just go to your wifi router and get the password from there?

Comment: @fsb sure thing but the idea was how to reveal the password from iOS. Since you can fo it on macOS it’s odd you can’t do it on the phone…

Comment: You can only do if jailbroken and then you get access to those files.  Otherwise, Apple doesn't provide a way to do it.

Comment: @fsb thanks. I think this would be better as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a way to directly view the wifi password.  There's 2 ways to do this:

1. Sync passwords via [iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/passwords-devices-ipada39a7fa0/ipados) and use your Mac's Keychain application to view the password.
2. Jailbreak your iPhone and use the available apps to access and display the password.

There's other ways that don't involve the iPhone, such as logging into your wifi router (from your iPhone or other device browser) to access the password, but per our comment discussion, this is something you're not looking for right now.